# Can the platinum jubilee bank holiday be cancelled?

Tags: united-kingdom, public-holidays

The [official list of UK bank holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays) includes a 'Platinum Jubilee' holiday scheduled for 3 June 2022 to mark the start of Queen Elizabeth's 70th year on the throne.

There is, naturally, some possibility that Queen Elizabeth's reign ends before this milestone is reached. If this were to occur, is there any provision to enable the cancellation of the proposed holiday? At what point does it become guaranteed?

Comment: I don't think it would be cancelled, but re-named, in that event.

Comment: Just to be pedantic it is the start of her 71st year on the throne - not the 70th. Indeed it is more than that because her 71st year began on 6th February this year - the anniversary of her father's death. The 2nd June was the start of her 70th "crowned" year - as the Coronation was on 2nd June 1953 - I remember it well as a then eight-year-old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bank holidays can be created or moved by a royal proclamation. In this case, a royal proclamation was used to move the statutory Spring bank holiday to early June. Another royal proclamation could reverse this.  There is no limit to when such a change can be made. So in theory it could happen at any time. No act of Parliament is needed.

In practice, even if the Queen dies, the bank holiday will remain (as a memorial weekend or something)

Comment: [Here's the proclamation in question](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/notice/3673204), as it appears in The Gazette.